# Change the background color of parts of a String inside Text

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I want to change the background color of part of a string displayed in Text, but how do I achieve this ?

```
if let subHeadline = viewModel.createSubHeadlineText() { 
  Text(subHeadline)
    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    .background(!viewModel.isNotSimilar ? Color.yellow: .clear)
}
```

currently in this code the whole text background is changed when the condition is true. But I want to change the background of only parts of subheadline.

Comment: You can use `AttributedString` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AttributeString (as mentioned in the comment).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(getAttributedString())
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func getAttributedString() -> AttributedString {
        let string = "This is yellow color"
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.yellow, range: NSRange(location: 8, length: 6))
        return AttributedString(attributedString)
    }
}
```

[image]